# Run jQuery.jcryption.js in JMeter to encrypt username and password

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am new to JMeter. My password is encrypted in Client side using jQuery.jcryption library. I get my secret key from server side and in client side using the key used to encrypt username and password. Then encrypted User Name and password is decrypted on server side based on same key.

My questions are:

1. How do i encrypt my data in JMeter at each thread run using jQuery.jcryption.js?
2. Is there any way to run jQuery files in JMeter?

I am stuck and not able to resolve this.

```
$.jCryption.getKeys("../account/getPublicKey.srvc?generateKeypair=true", 
function(receivedKeys) {
        var user = $("#userNameId").val();
        var password = $("#passwordId").val();
        $.jCryption.encrypt(user, receivedKeys, function(encrypted) {
            $.jCryption.encrypt(password, receivedKeys, function(encryptedPasswd) {
    $("#userNameHiddenId").val(encrypted);
    $("#passwordHiddenId").val(encryptedPasswd);
    validateAndSubmitLogin('form#loginForm');
            });
        });
    });
```